# Getting ZAP.yaml file error while automating ZAP docker scan during form authentication

Tags: docker, zap

I was trying to use form authentication while scanning application using ZAP's docker image.
Tried below command in PowerShell to scan application:
[Command executed in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfT4a.png)
zap.yaml: [Ref: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/automation-framework/environment/]
[yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw2Rs.png)
After executing the command in PowerShell getting below error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBS1L.png)

What is this error and where I can find log file for this error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you OS and what version of ZAP you are using.
As it looks you are using Windows then it should be in `C:\Users\<username>\OWASP ZAP\zap.log` - or `OWASP ZAP_D` forweekly or dev builds.

This is documented in https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/somethings-not-working-what-should-i-do/#check-the-log-file

The part of the yaml file you showed has various problems as per the error messages, eg the `urls` and `includePaths` should be lists.

My advice - create and test the plan using the ZAP desktop and then save the yaml file.

Comment: I tried to create context and use that context to login to screen while scanning. But its not working as its using Identity server that generate token at run time for authentiacation. Can you provide steps to generate yaml using ZAP desktop.